# bcm4331 wifi not detected in Cent OS 7.4 (mac) (EFI)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I have a MacBook Pro Mid-2012 with a bcm4331 wifi chip. I'm using Cent OS 7.4 and it can't detect my wifi hardware. I want to share that I've tried using wl-kmod from the website (which installs wl module) -

https://elrepo.org/tiki/wl-kmod

which worked although was giving frequent disconnection and was unable to connect to my university network most of the times ( which has a proxy ). So I tried using the method of installing b43 module, following instruction from the following website -

http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43/

which I did correctly (I think :P), but at the end it says that "modprobe: FATAL: Module b43 not found" as a response to "modprobe b43" input.

Please help me _/|\_ Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

The frequent disconnects are a known issue with wl-kmod and it is NOT the driver but the hardware itself, disable the dual band and sleep functionality and things should even out again.

With regards to b43, did you compile or install the epel release rpm of b43?

Comment: No sir, I don't know what is that. Can u help me in getting where to start from ?

Comment: He just did....

Comment: I tried to install b43-openfwwf from remirepo by adding the repository and then downloading the rpm from - https://rpms.remirepo.net/rpmphp/zoom.php?rpm=b43-openfwwf and installing it using "rpm -Uvh" but on no use :-(

Comment: sudo yum install b43-fwcutter is giving me response : No package b43-fwcutter available